# Discounts for Christmas on Ipod Touch?

Tags: ipod-touch

I am planning to get one iPod Touch from one of my friends who is coming from US this december end. The current price of iPod 32GB is around $299. How much discount can I expect this christmas?

Comment: We can't predict the future. Any answers here will just be speculation.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend heading on over to [AppleInsider](http://appleinsider.com).  They keep some really neat matrices of all the major Apple products and their prices at various online retailers.

For example, [the pricing matrix for the iPod touch](http://www.appleinsider.com/ipod_price_guide/) shows this for 2 Dec 2011:

[image: AppleInsider pricing matrix]

The best price is bolded.  It looks like you can get anywhere between 5 and 10% off an iPod touch, depending on which store you buy it from.  I'll also throw out there that if you have a friend who works for Apple, you might want to talk to him/her to see if they could help you get a discount as well.

Answer (score 0):

None unless you find another reseller with a discount.

As for Apple discounts, the only typical day of the year that Apple discounts in-store products is on 'Black Friday', the day after Thanksgiving in the US. Black Friday was a week ago from today. I wouldn't expect them to put anything on sale again before Christmas.

I have also been able to get Apple to price match if another local store has a valid non-Internet sale for the exact item. Do your homework, but if you walk into any store expect to pay the list price from here through Christmas.

You can also look on the Apple website for refurbished product or previous generation units which have a full warranty but a sale price.

Comment: While Apple might not be doing any sales on devices again before Christmas, they are offering free shipping on orders placed before December 22nd, 2011.  Depending on your circumstances, that may be a bigger savings than getting 5% off somewhere else.